# HTML link harvester

Tags: html, scraping, hyperlink

Can anyone suggest a program that can go through a list of URLs and scrape the URLs for a specific link?

I have roughly about 1000 links that I want to find if it has a specified page which ideally can be searched by keywords. I thought of writing my own program to do this but prefer not to reinvent the wheel.

The ideal script/program can be run on Windows or any Linux distribution and free.

Comment: We'll need much more information to provide a solid recommendation. Please see '[What is required for a question to contain “enough information”?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/46)' and [edit] your question to contain enough information. For starters, what operating system does it need to run on? What budget do you have?

Comment: Thanks, I have edited my question. I hope it qualifies.